# Iterator has an issue in working with next function

Tags: java, iterator

I have written the code below but I can't understand why it gives  `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Can any one please help me?

```
static LinkedList<Integer> l1 = new LinkedList<Integer>(); 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner ob= new Scanner(System.in);
            Iterator<Integer> l2=l1.iterator();
    ListIterator<Integer> l3=l1.listIterator();
    
    while(true)
    {
                    System.out.println("Enter number (press 0 to exit the loop: ");
        int number=ob.nextInt();
        if(number == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("****");
            break;
        }
        l3.add(number);
    }
            while(l2.hasNext())
                System.out.println(l2.next());
            
}
```

Comment: Gah! Try using names that actually mean something. `l1` is a list, but `l2` is an iterator? Not a good idea.

Comment: Your current code wouldn't even compile, due to using `hasnext` instead of `hasNext`. Please post *real* code which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: And you have `l2.Next()` rather than `l2.next()` (it should be all lower-case). Java is case sensitive.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `l2.next()` is fine.

Comment: @ZouZou: It was `l2.Next()` before the OP edited it (just as it was `l2.hasnext()`). (My comment was poorly-worded, it was only vaguely clear if you saw that the OP had `l2.Next()` in their code. I've reworded it a bit.)

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the mod exception because you're modifying the list *after* getting the iterator but *before* calling a method on the iterator. You're getting the iterator, then adding to the list (e.g., *modifying* it), then trying to use the iterator.

Two things:

1. Put your

   ```
   Iterator<Integer> l2=l1.iterator();
   ```

   line *after* the input loop.
2. Use `l1.add`, not `l3.add`, and do away with `l3` entirely. There's no reason (in this code) to use a `ListIterator` just to add to the list.